# Maximise Windows Vertically custom command

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

On kde there are built in keyboard shortcuts that expand the current windows either horizontally whilst keeping the vertical dimension or vice versa. I was hoping to add a custom keyboard shortcut to do this and was wondering what the command would be to implement it.